# Trying to Facebook Login process but getting exception about OAuthException

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm using facebook android sdk v4.7.0
Trying to facebook Login and getting an exception about:

> {Response: responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Syntax error "Expected name." at character 33: id, first_name, last_name, email,}}

Code below:

```
fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,");
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"me",
parameters,
HttpMethod.GET,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
prepareFacebookData(response.getJSONObject());
}
}
).executeAsync();
}
@Override
public void onCancel() {
printToastMessage("Canceled");
}
@Override
public void onError(FacebookException error) {
printToastMessage(error.getCause().toString());
}
});
```

Comment: Ok, so what do you think this message means ? What did you check already ? (so we don't do it again). Edit question and tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma here

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,");
```

That will make facebook expect another fields but there isn't so facebook will tell your request is invalid because you are passing extra empty string.

So the solution is to remove it to

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email");
```